# Microsoft Monitoring Agent Configuration

Tags: asp.net, .net, msbuild, intellitrace

I have recently started using the new cool feature of Visual Studio 2013 for debugging in deployment environment, **"Microsoft Monitoring Agent"**.

This tool, after installation and starting, can capture a snapshots of your web application and saved as an *IntelliTrace* (.itrace) file, and be opened in your developer's workstation in Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate.

For me, there are two feature-sets that are interesting.

1. *Logging Exceptions and Stack Traces and Process Memory Dump* :
   Where you can watch your running threads, start debugging them, etc.
2. *Connecting your assemblies with specific source control branch and version*: Where takes you to the related source code version after opening the .itrace file.

The latter requires a specific build configuration where a **BuildInfo.config** file is generated.

In case you are not familiar with Microsoft Monitoring Agent, [read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449058%28v=vs.120%29.aspx).

Anyways, I was able to make the first thing working pretty fine with our **existing** build results; But had not much luck in connecting the TFS Source code.

The reasons:

- Like I said, for creating this **BuildInfo.config**, you should make some changes in your build configuration. But it is almost with no effort in TFS 2013, and has some broken links in MSDN web site for TFS 2012 (which we are using).
- Even when building with Visual Studio, there seems to be a problem. Our product consists of **no single Web Project**. It is a semi-ERP system with multiple web projects and this BuildInfo.config file seems to be generated for each project. So I don't really know what we could do about this and how we can get that to work.

I also do not understand this:
What is the **BuildSymbolStorePath** which is required here and there?

I appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 1):

The [MSDN topic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449058%28v=vs.120%29.aspx#AutomatedBuild) has been updated, and you don't need to download the separate files anymore. Just do this:

1. Install any edition of Visual Studio 2013 on your Team Foundation Build server.
2. In your build definition, specify where to save the symbols files to index your source automatically. If you use a custom template, make sure that it has an activity to index your source.
3. Add these MSBuild arguments to your build definition:

   - /p:VisualStudioVersion=12.0
   - /p:MSBuildAssemblyVersion=12.0
   - /tv:12.0
   - /p:IncludeServerNameInBuildInfo=true
   - /p:BuildSymbolStorePath=<*path to symbols*>

For **BuildSymbolStorePath**, you must specify where you're storing the symbols that match your built code.

4.Run a new build.

Each project will create its own BuildInfo.config file, which goes in the same folder as the corresponding Web.config file.